# How to add 25 years(integer variable) to a date field in java

Tags: java, date

I want to add 25 years more to the date of birth field.

maxage is a int field of value 25.

```
if(table1.getregister_date() >= (employee.getdate_of_birth() + maxage))
//do something
```

want to know can i add and compare date fields this way??

Comment: You should provide more code or info about the context. For instance what are the return types of `table1.getregister_date()` and `employee.getdate_of_birth()`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: What is the exact type of your date field (returned by `getregister_date` and  `getdate_of_birth`)? Is it `java.util.Date`?

Comment: For any Date/Time framework I worked with in java: No. You need to tell it that it's years you want to add. How to do that depends on the framework.

Comment: Unrelated: [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type that `employee.getdate_of_birth()` returns. If its a `LocalDate`, you can do `employee.getdate_of_birth().plusYears(maxage)`. There are similar methods for days, months and seconds.

Comment: thanks.. i was just searching some methods like plusYears()

Comment: But while comparing with >= i am getting build error  bad operand types for binary operator '>='
[ERROR]   first type:  java.time.LocalDateTime
[ERROR]   second type: java.time.LocalDate

Comment: You're comparing `LocalDate` with `LocalDateTime`. You should convert first `LocalDateTime` to `LocalDate` using `LocalDate.from(yourLocalDateTimeVariable)` Difference between those classes is `LocalDateTime` stores info about hours, minutes and seconds and `LocalDate` have info just about year, month and day.

Comment: I typecasted so that now both is LocalDate....but still getting bad operand for ">=". Now both types are LocalDate only

Comment: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
[ERROR]   first type:  java.time.LocalDate
[ERROR]   second type: java.time.LocalDate

Comment: used method isAfter and isEqual to achive >=

Comment: Yeah thats also an option. The problem is there is not a method called `isGreaterOrEqual` so you need to do 2 comparations instead 1. I created some dummy test with two `LocalDate` objects and comparing them with `>=` and everything worked... not sure why you were getting that error.